# RedirectMatch don't work

Tags: apache, redirect, url-rewriting, http-redirect

I want to tell to my Apache that i want a redirect permanent rules.

I have theses 2 kinds of hits in my logs:

```
xx.xxx.xx.x - - [15/Mar/2013:08:14:21 +0100] "POST /oldEndPoint/services/toto HTTP/1.1" 200 - 6003 -
xx.xxx.xx.x - - [15/Mar/2013:08:15:40 +0100] "POST /newEndPoint/services/Tutu/toto HTTP/1.1" 200 - 1316 -
```

I want to tell to Apache, when he receive hits to /oldEndPoint/services/toto then he should do a redirect permanent (301) to the new url: /newEndPoint/services/Tutu/toto.

I have tried with this rule, but it's don't work, no redirect appear:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /modBackend/moderation/facebook /modFront/services/Moderation/facebook
```

Thanks!

Comment: `/modBackend/moderation/facebook` != `/oldEndPoint/services/toto`. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need [`RedirectMatch`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) for simple redirects.

See just [`Redirect`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) instead. You must give the old URL first and the new one last

```
Redirect /oldEndPoint/services/toto /newEndPoint/services/Tutu/toto
```